# Mopub banner ads - better control of loading/unloading

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mopub

I want to have fine control over a MoPub banner ad which appears over the top of my game app screen at specific times and not at others. My code currently looks like this (simplified):

```
LinearLayout linearlayout_for_banner = new LinearLayout (this);
mAdView = new MoPubView(this);
linearlayout_for_banner.addView(mAdView);
```

The linearlayout_for_banner is transparent, so when there is no advert, the user can see all of the game-play screen underneath. Then at a certain precise point I wish an ad to appear. At the moment, the only function I know to call is `mAdView.loadAd()` which as far as I know begins a process of going to the internet to seek an ad, then if it finds one it will be drawn on the screen. This is very unsatisfactory, because there is often a delay before it appears. So what I would like are functions like `scoop_an_advert_but_dont_show_it_yet()` and `now_show_that_ad_you_scooped_earlier()`. Do they exist? Mopub's documentation seems rather inadequate on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try browsing their github wiki: https://github.com/mopub/mopub-client/wiki/CustomEventsAndroid

You want their, "onReceiveAd" method. Check it out, seems like exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with preloading ads and not showing them until a specific time. You can use `loadAd()` for this. Just swap the visibility of the view when you want it to appear.

**NOTE:** If you do, you should set that particular ad to *not* "refresh every x seconds" on the mopub site. Otherwise, it will end up as unintentional ad fraud, since the ad will be refreshing itself while invisible(not to mention tank your CTR).

If you have other ads running in the app without this requirement, I'd recommend a separate ad unit for your sometimes-invisible one, so you can still do the refresh on the other one.